# Protocol conforming to Sequence protocol while eliminating generic constraint issue

Tags: swift, generics, tree, protocols, sequence

Attempting to create a protocol that is used to create different nodes within a tree. A simplified version is:

```
protocol NodeElement {
    var children: [NodeElement] { get }
}
```

This protocol can be used to create *struct*s that can be used to create nodes into a tree.

```
struct TextNode: NodeElement {
    var text: String
    var children: [NodeElement]
}

struct NumberNode: NodeElement {
    var number: Int
    var children: [NodeElement]
}
```

and with these structs, a Tree can be created containing varying types.

`let root = TextNode(text: "Hello", children: [NumberNode(...), ...])`

I would like **NodeElement** to conform to the Sequence Protocol to allow for pre-order tree traversal within a `for...in` loop.

This can be done through

```
protocol NodeElement: Sequence { ... }

extension NodeElement {
    func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<NodeElement> {
        var stack: [NodeElement] = [self]

        return AnyIterator {
            if let next = stack.first {
                stack.remove(at: 0)
                stack.insert(contentsOf: next.content, at: 0)
                return next
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

If this is done, the following **ERROR** occurs:

```
error: protocol 'NodeElement' can only be used as a generic constraint
because it has Self or associated type requirements

var content: [NodeElement] { get }
              ^
```

This occurs even when I believe I am fully conforming to the Sequence protocol.

Without making a NodeElement a **struct** and having all nodes inherit from it, is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Please provide coherent code examples.  Your protocol is defined using NodeElements, is that different from NodeElement or is the "s" a typo) ?  It also does not have a content variable.  Is that the same as children or something else in another place ?

Comment: They were the same, it has been fixed in the code examples.

Answer (score 0):

NodeElement has a reference to itself so it cannot be used to define a concrete type.  You will not be able to make it a Sequence because of this.

You could however achieve something similar by simply adding a computed variable to the protocol instead of making it a sequence per se.

for Example:

```
extension NodeElement 
{
    var treeNodes : AnyIterator<NodeElement>  
    {
        var stack: [NodeElement] = [self]

        return AnyIterator {
            if let next = stack.first {
                stack.remove(at: 0)
                stack.insert(contentsOf: next.children, at: 0)
                return next
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

You will then be able to use your protocol in a for ... in loop using that variable:

```
for node in root.treeNodes
{
   ...
}
```